# MCMC Metropolis-Hastings Understanding

Tags: mathematical-statistics, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo

I am having trouble understanding a key aspect of MCMC - does the collection of states the Markov chain passes through represent the target distribution, or for a single sample, are we running $n$ Markov chains of length $d$ and taking the $n$ states $x_d^{(1)}...x_d^{(n)}$ to be our sample?

While I am under the impression that the correct answer is the former, I am interested in why the following justification for the latter would be incorrect.

Say you are interested in sampling from a target distribution $\pi$ so you construct a Markov chain with a stationary distribution $\pi$.

Now, you start running your Markov chain. Does the property of a stationary distribution not say that only the final state $x_n$ for some large $n$ will follow $\pi$. And if so, the first $n-1$ samples of the Markov chain are waste? If this is the case, it would be my impression that MCMC requires that for a sample $x^{(t)} =  (x_1^{(t)}, x_2^{(t)}, ... x_d^{(t)})$ each $x_i^{(t)}$ would be the $d$th element from a Markov chain with stationary distribution $\pi$ run for a long period of time.

When looking at examples of code, however, this does not seem to be whats going on, but I cannot grasp what really is going on if the first $n-1$ realized states of the Markov chain do not follow the stationary distribution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no notion of achieving the limiting distribution for a Metropolis-Hastings kernel, unless your proposal is equivalent to your distribution of interest. MCMC as a class of algorithms are asymptotically exact, as, for example
$$\Vert P^k(x_{k-1}, x_k) - \pi\Vert_{TV} \rightarrow 0 $$ 
so the kernel associated with the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm converges to the stationary distribution in the limit.

To argue that our samples come from the target distribution, we usually run the algorithm for some fixed number of iterations until the algorithm has 'warmed up' or 'burned in'. By this we mean that the algorithm has reached the [typical set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typical_set) of the distribution, and is therefore now producing samples from the distribution. These aren't correctly distributed, but (hopefully) very close.